# Access different serializer if a queryset is empty Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I don't think I am implementing this correctly, but I am trying to change the serializer used for a queryset based on a condition (if there are no venues in one queryset, switch to another serializer and just return list object). I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Here is the view

```
class SavedVenuesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserVenueSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        list_id = self.request.GET.get('list_id', None)
        user = self.request.user.id
        print(user)
        print(list_id)
        print(type(list_id))
        qs = UserVenue.objects.filter(user_list=int(float(list_id)))
        if not qs:    
            print("EMPTY LIST") #this is where i try to switch serializer
            serializer_class = UserListSerializer
            return UserVenue.objects.filter(id=int(float(list_id)))
        else:
            return qs
```

Here are the relevant serializers:

```
class UserVenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = mapCafesSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserVenue
        fields = ['user', 'user_list', 'venue']
        depth = 2 

[...]

class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = UserList
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'list_name']
        depth = 2
```

The traceback isn't throwing an error but it isn't doing what I am hoping:

```
1
45
<class 'str'>
EMPTY LIST
[29/Sep/2021 11:05:36] "GET /api/savedvenues/?list_id=45 HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is the correct practice to change `serializer` class in `ModelViewSet`:**

You have to override `get_serializesr_class` method:

```
class SavedVenuesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserVenueSerializer
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if not self.get_queryset():  # Check your conditions here
            return UserListSerializer
        else:
            return UserVenueSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove serializer_class field from your view, and create [get_serializer_class()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) method, that will contain the logic for choosing the serializer. Is the best practice.

But, you can also, do it in your get queryset.

First, remove serializer_class attribute from your view. Instead, set it inside your get_queryset method (with this.serializer_class);

```
def get_queryset(self):
    list_id = self.request.GET.get('list_id', None)
    qs = UserVenue.objects.filter(user_list=int(float(list_id)))
    if not qs:
        self.serializer_class = UserVenueSerializer  
        return UserVenue.objects.filter(id=int(float(list_id)))
    else:
        self.serializer_class = UserListSerializer
        return qs
```

Don't forget use the self.serializer_class.

Comment: Instead of `this` use `self`. `this` is java stuff

Comment: Sure, you're right... it's force of habit